# Hide content from anonymous without modifying master page

Tags: permissions

I want to hide sections in seattle.master, but without modifying the master page in office 365. How can I achieve that? I know I can inject javascript in my master page based on the user that's logged it, but this functionality is only client side and users will be able to go around this and view the sections I need to hide anyway.

how do I do it?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to hide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding only webParts set with a Target Audience?

[image]
<sub>(source: [netdna-cdn.com](http://csharpcorner.mindcrackerinc.netdna-cdn.com/article/sharepoint-online-office-365-column-level-security-iss/Images/image001.png))</sub>